# Regex for space separated 60 number values exactly

Tags: regex

Can anybody help me to write regex for space separated 60 number values? The values can be float numbers or integers.

For example: "90.90 78.54 34 ...." (60 values) or "89.43 90 34 ...." (60 values).

I tried the following one

```
^(\s*([0-9]|[0-9.])+\s*){60}$
```

But, this causes the browser to crash.

Comment: "this is going browser to be crashed" - browsers per se doesn't support regular expressions, where do you want to use regex?

Comment: I am using regex in javascript code...so when it gets called browser getting crashed

Comment: What's the object and code you're calling it with?

Comment: calling it in angularJS ng-pattern for input text field..

Answer (score 3):

Some problems with your expression:

`^(\s*([0-9]|[0-9.])+\s*){60}$`

- why do you have `\s*` both at the beginning and the end? One of them (at the end) would be enough
- `\s*`: why `*`? Whitespace isn't optional, there must be whitespace between numbers (if you want to cover situation where last number is end of the string, then you can use `([0-9.]+\s+){59}[0-9.]+`
- `([0-9]|[0-9.])` - `[0-9.]` would be enough, saving a lot of steps for the regex engine
- `^...$` - do you want to select 60 numbers, or just validate that a string consists of 60 numbers? (your approach shows the second one).

So the correct expression would be:

- `([0-9.]+\s+){59}[0-9.]+`,
- or including leading and trailing spaces:
  `\s*([0-9.]+\s+){59}[0-9.]+\s*`,
- and optionally you can enclose it between `^...$`

Comment: Thanks..Its 100% correct.. but may I know can we check or trim leading and trailing whitespace in regex ? like "  90 43 ....  "

Comment: ye, I've updated my answer

Comment: I'm happy it works! please consider accepting if you feel it solved your problem (http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers).